# I am having issues with showing the output of my array in a message box

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, messagebox

I am trying to show the output of an array that has been defined as a string in VBA Excel.  However, I am not getting the output I am looking for.  This is my code:

```
Sub myArray()
    Dim dayArray(0 To 6) As String
        i = dayArray(i)
        dayArray(0) = "Sunday"
        dayArray(1) = "Monday"
        dayArray(2) = "Tuesday"
        dayArray(3) = "Wednesday"
        dayArray(4) = "Thursday"
        dayArray(5) = "Friday"
        dayArray(6) = "Saturday"
    For i = 0 To 6
        MsgBox "Today is "
    Next
End Sub
```

I am trying to output the day of the week based on the string. How can I make sure that I get the day as the message box?

Comment: Are you looking for `MsgBox "Today is " & dayArray(i)`?

Comment: I was trying to output the day and tried to use i for the numbers 0 through 6.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Do you want to `MsgBox` the day of the week that today is? If so, you don't need that array, just use `MsgBox "Today is " & Format(Now, "dddd")`. If not, can you clarify what you mean by "How can I make sure that I get the day as the message box?"

Comment: Yes.  Also, I made the change that you showed.  However, all that I am getting is a message box saying that "Today is Monday" coming up seven times.

Comment: If you just want the day of the week that today is, all you need is that one line... You can get rid of the array and `For...Next` loop

Comment: I am trying to be able to display each day on its own message box.

Comment: Then use the code in my original comment. Add a `Dim i as long` and get rid of the `i = dayArray(i)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question out:

```
Sub myArray()
    Dim dayArray(0 To 6) As String

    dayArray(0) = "Sunday"
    dayArray(1) = "Monday"
    dayArray(2) = "Tuesday"
    dayArray(3) = "Wednesday"
    dayArray(4) = "Thursday"
    dayArray(5) = "Friday"
    dayArray(6) = "Saturday"

    Dim i as Long
    For i = 0 To 6
        MsgBox "Today is " & dayArray(i)
    Next
End Sub
```